# Multiple Login Page with Identity Core and Asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I Have an Asp.net Core Application with 2 areas, each area has its own login page.
I use this code to redirect the user to the login page :

```
  services.AddAuthentication(opt => { opt.DefaultScheme = "AdminAuth";})
                    .AddCookie("UserAuth", opt => { opt.LoginPath = "/User/Login"; opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied";  })
                    .AddCookie("AdminAuth", opt => { opt.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login"; opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/Admin/Dashboard/AccessDenied"; });
```

after submitting the login form, the user login successfully but didn't go to the controller and come back to the login page.
I Use these attributes for controllers :
for Admin :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "AdminAuth")]
```

for Users :

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "User", AuthenticationSchemes = "UserAuth")]
```

and for login, I am using this code :

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Comment: Does each login page have it's own users? It's probably going to be easier to split the site into two apps.

Comment: I can't split this web app into two web apps.

Comment: Sure, have 2 login forms, but one list of users, with user / admin roles. Each login form can validate the appropriate role, add a user claim, and match against an authentication policy. Just because you want to separate authorisation, doesn't mean you want separate authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Identity encapsulates the basic cookie authentication method. But identity does not provide cookie settings corresponding to the scheme.

I suggest you use cookie authentication, and add cookies to the specified scheme. Or one of the businesses uses basic cookie authentication. While another business uses identity.

Please make sure to indicate these schemas when
use `HttpContext.SignInAsync("schema",claimsPrincipal)`. Otherwise, it will only generate  the default schema's cookie which you configure in startup.

This is an example of user login.

```
    public IActionResult login()
    {
        string username = "username";
        string userpassword = "password";
        var userClaim = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"User")
            };
        var personIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaim, "identitycard");
        var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { personIdentity });

        HttpContext.SignInAsync("UserAuth", principle);
        return Redirect("resource");
    }
```

Then, two cookies will be written to the browser.

[image]

Comment: Actually,I want to using _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false); function.

Comment: @MyPv90, Identity has encapsulated basic cookie authentication, so you can use another method. Please refer to this answer which I have updated.

Comment: in your answer, how can I use  password for login?

Comment: If you use both identity and cookie authentication. The login in the identity part does not need to be changed. You only need to specify the scheme during cookie authentication login. I strongly recommend that you use basic cookie authentication. Because identity is an encapsulation of cookie authentication.  Scheme cannot be specified in the interface it provides.